# Omniauth-identity InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I followed this [railcasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txZk-ZnEnqU) tutorial on how to implement Omniauth-identity but hit a snag.

When I try to register the user the following error pops up

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in SessionsController#create
```

In the console logs the following error pops up

```
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"asdasd asdasd", "email"=>"asd@yopmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "provider"=>"identity"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

The user is inserted in the Identity model without problems but when the application tries to create a session it is all for naught.

Here is the relevant code I am using

**Gemfile**

## OpenID Authentication

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-identity'
```

**initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
    provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
    provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET']
    provider :identity
end
```

**routes**

```
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  post 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

**SessionsController**

```
def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed In!"
end
```

**Users model**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || create_with_omniauth(auth)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error `InvalidAuthenticityToken` raised when Rails check the [`CSRF`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) token, you can disable [`CSRF`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) protection on controller by skipping the verification [`skip_before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html), add to the top of your `SessionsController`:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create
```

**But you must be careful and read all about the [`CSRF`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) protection.**

Comment: Fixed my problem, will check the documentation you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

Quoting as it is from the [source](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection/issues/8#issuecomment-659603672):

> I just spent quite some time debugging this. In my case, I was following an auth0 tutorial that instructed to generate a link with <%= button_to "Login", "auth/auth0", method: :post %>. I was banging my head to a wall for a long time because of the InvalidAuthenticityToken exception.

Turns out that the path had to be "/auth/auth0" (slash in the beginning) for rails to correctly compare the path. Shrug. Maybe this helps someone else. Not sure if this is actually a Rails bug.. it seems at least little unfriendly.